# Java redeclare inherited interfaces?

Tags: java, interfaces, inheritance

While working on a small class called `FractionNumber` I found asking myself if I should implement an interface that I am already implementing. Sounds stupid, I know, but bear with me.

My class `FractionNumber` extends `Number`; `Number` implements `Serializable`. And I am unsure if `FractionNumber` should explicitly implement `Serializable` as well.

Of course it does not really matter because `Serializable` only defines final methods and `FractionNumber` inherits the `Serializable` 'implementation' of `Number`. But I kind of like making my `FractionNumber` explicitly `Serializable`.

Now to my question: Is this simply useless or does the verbosity help in some way? Does it make sense, in a philosophically sense, to declare `FractionNumber` being something it already is?

Comment: You might just remind that in a JavaDoc comment. Or add a line comment before the class fields to warn yourself before you try to modify them. Though, if you have a serialVersionUID, it probably gives enough reminder.

Comment: I'm not after reminding me or other people that this class is searializable (all the fields are primitive so there is no danger there). I only want the class to be clearly serializable - also only because I think any class meant to store information _should_ be serializable.

But maybe you're right with your last point, the `serialVersionUID` field indicates that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## From a code point of view

Contracts set by the parent type should be implied for the sub type.

If you feel the need to express serialization abilities in every type that can be serialized *(maybe you feel you need to explicitly remind yourself/co-developers that something can be serialized)* you should refactor your code to strengthen the implication.

## From a JavaDoc point of view

All interfaces implemented by the type, *including inherited interfaces*, are displayed in the header under "*All implemented interfaces*". The only difference is the actual declaration displayed in the JavaDoc:

**If directly implementing interface**:

```
public class Sub extends Super implements Serialization
```

**If inherited**:

```
public class Sub extends Super
```

To me, this is clutter (duplication), and I recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you probably should not be redeclaring that you implement interfaces in this way but `Serializable` is not a normal interface.  You say that "`Serializable` only defines final methods" but that's not the case ([I double-checked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)).  `Serializable` declares no methods at all.  It's a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) which is widely considered to be an anti-pattern and I am in full agreement with that assessment.

The fact that your class must be serializable because a super-class (or interface) implements `Serializable` is an artifact one of the most prominent design flaws in Java.  `Serializable` is specifed using an interface but `transient` is a keyword.  Why `serializable` isn't a keyword too is a bit of a head scratcher.  If java serialization was designed now, it likely would be done with annotations.

Because of all this wackiness, if you are going to implement `Serializable`, I would go ahead and redeclare it to show that you actually intend it to work with java serialization and that it's not `Serializable` because simply because a base class was declared that way.  Personally, I wouldn't use java serialization, though.  There are many better ways to create wireformat and I think the idea of 'object transmission' is inherently flawed.